# Android FullScreen

Tags: android, android-layout, television

I am developing Android application using eclipse. I have noticed one thing and that is the app is not showing on full screen. There are blank black spaces around the borders of the application in Android TV Box. I have tried every full screen property(Match_Parent, fill_parent) but still not successful.

Comment: Can you post your layout and perhaps a screenshot showing the problem?

Comment: Ok ianhanniballake thank you for quick reply but i got it now, it was some settings issue in the TV Box display configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who has same question about Android TV box, the answer is to go in settings and then Display. It contains the option of Display Position where you can set the zoom in and zoom out properties to stretch or compress your screen display.

Answer (score 3):

Add theme in the Manifest file with your activity name.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
```